# Transfer mysql query to NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm writing mysql query, that gets info correctly, but i cannot write NSPredicate for this, because I don't know how to select IN (select) construction.

```
SELECT * FROM ZPHOTO WHERE ZPHOTOID IN (SELECT ZALBUMID FROM ZPHOTO) AND ZALBUMID = 0;
```

I take all rows, where albumID = 0, and if albumID contains this photoID .

and a part of my nspredicate:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
etchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoId IN"]
```

**UPDATED:**
Logic:
There is a table : [screenshot here](https://api.monosnap.com/image/download?id=H33APSx4ZVwRf99tpNx5rnzhw). I need return a row where albumId = 0 and if photoId for this row is found in albumId entity. In this example i need return first row.
Logic: if albumId = 0, it is album, if albumId != 0, that means,that photo belongs to 1-st photo album. So i need return all albums, where number of photos not nil. 
with this predicate, i only returns all albums, also albums without photos .

```
"albumId = 0"
```

So i need to filter albums without photos.
please help me

**UPDATED 2:**

return any rows without photos,i think trouble with (photoId IN %@) ,i think he found in ZPK,not in albumId entity.

```
        NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        fr.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"albumId != %i",statSubId]; // != 0
        [fr setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *albumIds = [context executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error];

        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"photoId" ascending:YES];
        [fr setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoId IN %@ AND albumId == %i", albumIds,statSubId];
```

**Updated 3**

it seems like a properly working solution. thank you guys!

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"albumId != %i",statSubId]; // != 0

NSError *error;
NSArray *albumIds = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSMutableArray *albId = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Photo *photo in albumIds) {
    [albId addObject:photo.albumId];
}

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoId IN %@ AND albumId == %i", albId,statSubId];
```

Comment: It would help if you describe how the Photo entity is defined (attributes, relationships).

Comment: What *Core Data entities* have you defined? Photo, Album, ...? What properties do they have? - Note that Core Data uses relationships between entities and not ids or foreign keys. It could be that you translated the SQL tables "too verbatim" to Core Data.

Comment: About photo i have only one entity,photo and defined properties photoId,albumId, that is NSNumber, title and text. I get photo info from server, and cannot change structure, they send me info like this.

Comment: On this structure i already did all app, it's last thing. Also i have entity Stat,where have statId and statSubId and worked like with photos, but i needn't to filter those pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to achieve that with a single Core Data fetch request.
You have to do this in two steps:

- Fetch all objects with `albumId != 0` and store the resulting ids in an array `albumIds`.
- Use the predicate

  ```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"albumId == 0 AND photoId IN %@", albumIds]
  ```

  to get your desired result.

Comment: Or do you just need all albumIds that are not 0?

Comment: On current page i need to show only albums, so find rows where albumId = 0

Comment: hm,it's strange,but there are any attributes,that haven't they albumID != 0

Comment: @gronzzz: I am sorry but I do not understand your last comment. If my answer does not work then let me know and I will try to help.

Comment: ok, it seems i'm found not best, but a worked solution. i posted this in updated 3,thank you for idea!

Comment: @gronzzz: Your `albumIds` is an array of Photo objects. You need an array or set of *numbers* for the second fetch request. Try `NSArray *albums = [context executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error]; NSArray *albumIds = [albums valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.albumId"];`

Answer (score 0):

u can use this:

```
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"photoId IN(albumId FROM Photo)"]; 
NSPredicate *markPredicate     = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ZALBUMID = 0"];
NSPredicate *finalPredicate    = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                     @[compoundPredicate, markPredicate]];
```

Comment: I get this error : Unable to parse the format string "photoId IN(albumId FROM Photo)" . I think, that it's incorrect to use FROM in predicate .

Comment: @gronzzz: It is almost impossible to give a correct solution to your problem if we don't know how the entity is defined.

Comment: There is a table : https://api.monosnap.com/image/download?id=H33APSx4ZVwRf99tpNx5rnzhw
I need return a row where albumId = 0 and if photoId for this row is found in albumId entity. In this example i need return first row.